# Bootstrap Tour and Animation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-animations, bootstrap-tour

Can I apply this [CSS Animation](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) into Bootstrap Tour by using the callback

```
function onShow:function (tour) { 
    // before show next step, addClass animate into the Bootstrap popover
}
```

Comment: You need something like loading spinner ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is a little bit older, but you still have no option to add other animations.

I've created a little workaround to integrate every animation from Animate.css into your Bootstrap Tour:

Just use the `onHide` and `onShow` functions in the tour configuration.

```
onHide: function(tour){
    $(".tour-"+tour_name).addClass('animated fadeOutRight');
},
onShown: function(tour){
    $(".tour-"+tour_name).css("opacity","0");
    setTimeout(function(){ //To be sure that it is on the right place
        $(".tour-"+tour_name).css("opacity","1");
        $(".tour-"+tour_name).addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    }, 320); //Increase here the number if the positions are wrong
},
```

Also important is that you set for every step the `animation` to `false`.

```
{
    element: "#bst_element",
    title: "Foo title",
    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
    placement:"left",
    backdrop: false,
    animation: false //<-- Set to false
}
```

I hope that this question might help other users as well.